# Reading file remotly using paramiko (or not) in python

Tags: python, ssh, remote-access, paramiko

I would like to read a file in a remote machine. I can do it using `paramiko`.

The file is constantly updated by newlines. I have tried to implement a python script for reading it. Here the interesting part of the code:

```
import glob
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import os
import pandas as pd
from scipy.linalg import norm
import time
import paramiko
import select

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    print("...starting")

    # a lot of stuff here in the middle

    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh_client.connect(hostname='xxx.xx.xx.xxx',username='user',password='pass')

    print("...starting transport:")
    transport = ssh_client.get_transport()
    channel = transport.open_session()
    channel.exec_command("cat /tmp/ciao.txt")
    while True:
        rl, wl, xl = select.select([channel],[],[],0.0)
        #print(rl.readlines())
        if len(rl) > 0:
            #print("printing")
            string_in_file = channel.recv(1024)
            if len(string_in_file) > 0:
                #print("printing")
                print(string_in_file)
```

**Problem**: the file is correctly read at the beginning and after, every newly written line is completely ignored or, at least, it does not produce any effect on the output of the proposed script. Any suggestions on how to read new lines when written?

Any other idea on how to achieve the same result (even without `paramiko`) is more than welcome. The only restriction is the use of python.

Comment: Instead of `cat` you could use `tail -f`

Comment: `channel.exec_command("cat /tmp/ciao.txt")` Instead of running a command, you should consider opening an SFTP channel and fetching the file through that. Paramiko probably has a method that lets you read the file contents as a stream instead of writing it to a local file.

Comment: @tdelaney, the same result: it passes the line in the file but, if other lines are added (in the remote file), nothing happens on the script side.

Comment: @Kenster, thank you for point out this. I am trying to find other information to solve this problem. If you have other keyword to suggest, please do it :)

Comment: `tail -f` worked for me. I'll post it as an answer to show my work and if something is wrong we can work it there.

Answer (score 0):

`tail -f` will keep following the file giving you more output as you go.

```
import glob
import sys
import os
import time
import paramiko
import select

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    print("...starting")

    # a lot of stuff here in the middle

    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()

    # for test get "user,pw" in ./test.pw
    user, pw = open('test.pw').readline().strip().split(",")
    ssh_client.connect(hostname='localhost',username=user,password=pw)

    print("...starting transport:")
    transport = ssh_client.get_transport()
    channel = transport.open_session()
    # 1GB is include first Gig - just a way to get all of the 
    # file instead of the last few lines
    # include --follow=name instead of -f if you want to keep
    # following files that are log rotated
    channel.exec_command("tail -f --lines=1GB /tmp/test.txt")
    while True:
        # (don't melt cpu's with a zero timeout)
        rl, wl, xl = select.select([channel],[],[])
        #rl, wl, xl = select.select([channel],[],[],0.0)
        if rl:
            string_in_file = channel.recv(1024)
            if len(string_in_file) > 0:
                print(string_in_file)
            else:
                print("channel disconnected")
                break
```